# How to implement event-driven JavaScript without involving any DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

Is there any way to implement event-driven programming in JavaScript, without involving any DOM element? Such as creating an event-handler which executed every time an array get sorted.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sure! The keyword you're looking for is "pubsub". Here are some well-known implementations:

- [As a jQuery plugin](http://higginsforpresident.net/js/static/jq.pubsub.js)
- [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS)
- [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2)
- [Backbone.Events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events)

But you could also do it yourself, like so:

```
window.pubsub = (function () {
    var eventToListeners = {};

    return {
        sub: function (event, callback) {
            if (!eventToListeners.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
                eventToListeners[event] = [];
            }
            eventToListeners[event].push(callback);
        },
        pub: function (event, args) {
            if (eventToListeners.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < eventToListeners[event].length; ++i) {
                   try {
                       eventToListeners[event][i].call(null, args);
                   } catch (e) {
                       if (console && console.error) {
                           console.error(e);
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}());

// Sample usage:
pubsub.sub("arraySorted", function () {
    console.log("array was sorted");
});

var myArray = [2, 3, 1];

myArray.sort();
pubsub.pub("arraySorted");
```

Comment: Remember to wrap the call in a try-catch block to ensure all subscribers are called even if one fails.

Comment: @Magnar: Thanks for the suggestion; implemented!

Comment: Whoa!! thank you  so much!! 
i never knew about this Pub/Sub thingy before.
it really helped me out! 
thx :)

Comment: @Domenic thanks for the answer, I think this is one of the most clear and simple answers related to Pub/Sub that I've found so far.

Comment: Great ! i just want to point out that "pubSub" is just a random function name. Any other would work as well. In my Opinion something like "customEvent" would match it better :)

Answer (score 3):

In newish browsers, we've added the ability to construct an EventTarget directly:

```
const et = new EventTarget();

et.addEventListener("arraySorted", () => {
  console.log("array was sorted");
});

const myArray = [2, 3, 1];

myArray.sort();
et.dispatchEvent(new Event("arraySorted"));
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/EventTarget for more examples as well as a browser compatibility table. As of the time of this writing it only works in Chrome (64+) and Firefox (59+), but over time support will expand to include Safari and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Backbone.Events into your object would give you this.  (See Backbone.js)